# This keyword becomes the wrong this

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

All `this` keywords inside the `onScroll` function becomes the wrong `this`, inside the function it becomes the `window` which makes sense. I want to use the `=>` notation to preserve `this` but in this scenario I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax or where to even put it to make it right.

Storing `this` in a `public self = this` doesn't work either for some odd reason, but I would prefer a solution using `=>`

Here's the class:

```
export class ScrollXDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild(FormDatepickerPresetsComponent) presets: FormDatepickerPresetsComponent;

  public posX: number = 0;
  public offset: number = 35;

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer, private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {

    let wrapper: HTMLElement = this.presets.presetsWrapperElement.nativeElement;
    let scrollHandler: string = 'DOMMouseScroll' in window ? 'DOMMouseScroll' : 'mousewheel';   

    this._renderer.listen(wrapper, scrollHandler, _.debounce(this.onScroll, 200));
  }

  onScroll(e: any) {

    e.preventDefault();

    let delta = (e.type === 'DOMMouseScroll' ? e.detail * -40 : e.wheelDelta);

    let list: HTMLElement = this.presets.presetsListElement.nativeElement;
    let totalWidth = list.offsetWidth;

    if (delta > 0) {

      if (this.posX >= 0) {
        return false;
      }

      this.posX = this.posX + this.offset;

      this._renderer.setElementStyle(list, 'margin-left', this.posX + 'px');
    }
    else {

      let listX = list.getBoundingClientRect().right;
      let hostX = this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().right;

      if (listX <= hostX) {
        return false;
      }

      this.posX = this.posX - this.offset;

      this._renderer.setElementStyle(list, 'margin-left', this.posX + 'px');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should work:

```
 _.debounce(this.onScroll.bind(this), 200)
```

See also documentation **[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**

Another way:

```
onScroll = (e: any) => {
  ...
}
```